# What kind of Java object must be passed to Google Charts trendline?

Tags: java, charts, google-visualization

JSON is created with `Gson` by passing a `List<List<Trendline>>` as parameter.

Object `Trendline` follows:

```
private double state;
private double planogram;
private double mix;
private double share;
private double execution;
private String annotation;
// constructors, getters and setters
```

In the JavaScript portion, after creating the columns, each row is added:

```
var i = 0;
for (var key in trendline) {
    var row = trendline[key];
    for (var prop in row) {
        if (row.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            if (i === 0) {
                stateName = row[prop];
            }
            if (i === 1) {
                planogram = row[prop];
            }
            if (i === 2) {
                mix = row[prop];
            }
            if (i === 3) {
                share = row[prop];
            }
            if (i === 4) {
                execution = row[prop];
            }
            if (i === 5) {
                annotation = row[prop];
            }
        }
        i = i+1;
    }
    row = new Array(stateName, planogram, mix, share, execution, annotation);
    columnData.addRow(row);
}
```

The chart is being displayed, but no data was loaded, even after setting manual values to those variables in the Java method.

Answer (score 0):

Used [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) as a helper for building the POJO. The JSON code I pasted was from [Google Charts documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example):

```
{
  "cols": [
        {"id":"","label":"Topping","pattern":"","type":"string"},
        {"id":"","label":"Slices","pattern":"","type":"number"}
      ],
  "rows": [
        {"c":[{"v":"Mushrooms","f":null},{"v":3,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Onions","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Olives","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Zucchini","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Pepperoni","f":null},{"v":2,"f":null}]}
      ]
}
```

It created 4 classes, which I modified a bit (see end of this answer): `GCDataTable` (that's typed in "Class Name"), `Col`, `Row` and `C`.

---

The code which builds the JSON string follows (using [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)):

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();

GCDataTable dataTable = new GCDataTable();

List<Col> cols = new ArrayList<>();

Col col1 = new Col();
col1.setId("");
col1.setLabel("Label 1");
col1.setPattern("");
col1.setType("number");
cols.add(col1);

Col col2 = new Col();
col2.setId("");
col2.setLabel("Label 2");
col2.setPattern("");
col2.setType("number");
cols.add(col2);

Col col3 = new Col();
col3.setId("");
col3.setLabel("Label 3");
col3.setPattern("");
col3.setType("number");
cols.add(col3);

Col col4 = new Col();
col4.setId("");
col4.setLabel("Label 4");
col4.setPattern("");
col4.setType("number");
cols.add(col4);

Col col5 = new Col();
col5.setId("");
col5.setLabel("Label 5");
col5.setPattern("");
col5.setType("number");
cols.add(col5);

dataTable.setCols(cols);

List<Row> rows = new ArrayList<>();

listOne.stream().map((_item) -> new ArrayList<>()).forEach((cList) -> {
    Row row = new Row();
    listTwo.stream().map((obj) -> {
        C c = new C();
        c.setV(obj.getAttribute());
        return c;
    }).map((c) -> {
        c.setF(null);
        return c;       
    }).map((c) -> {
        cList.add(c);
        return c;       
    }).map((_item) -> {
        row.setC(cList);
        return _item;
    }).forEach((_item) -> {
        rows.add(row);
    });
});

dataTable.setRows(rows);
trendlineJson = gson.toJson(dataTable);
```

Then, instead of iterating through each row, I passed the generated JSON to `google.visualization.DataTable`'s constructor, like this:

```
var dataTable = #{managedBean.trendlineJson}
var columnData = new google.visualization.DataTable(dataTable);
```

---

Java 7's for-each:

```
for (String str : listOne) {
    List<Object> cList = new ArrayList<>();
    Row row = new Row();
    for (Object obj : listTwo) {
        C c = new C();
        c.setV(obj.getAttribute());
        c.setF(null);
        cList.add(c);
        row.setC(cList);
        rows.add(row);
    }
}
```

---

- [GCDataTable](http://pastebin.com/N0hmaUbh) (Pastebin)
- [Col](http://pastebin.com/q4GDHRER) (Pastebin)
- [Row](http://pastebin.com/53wEYsCs) (Pastebin)
- [C](http://pastebin.com/TgSTNsu6) (Pastebin)